# sql query WHERE equal or empty

Tags: php, mysql, select

What is the proper way to do a an sql query in this case. For example: The only problem is sometimes they may not select bedroom, so we need to pull up all bedrooms and sometimes we need to pull up only 3 bedrooms. So bedrooms is sometimes empty.

```
$bedroom = $_REQUEST['bedroom'];

SELECT * FROM apartments WHERE bedrooms = '$bedroom'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM apartments WHERE ('$bedroom' = '' OR bedrooms = '$bedroom')
```

Note that you also shouldn't substitute variables directly into the query, you should use a prepared statement with parameters. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1). So it should actually be:

```
SELECT * FROM apartments WHERE ('$bedroom' = ? OR bedrooms = ?)
```